# Splitting display in Android for different Apps

Tags: java, android

I'm creating middleware app for android which in main think will allow people create games based on blocks easily. The idea comes from Siftables (sifteo cubes) - I'm creating Android version :)

The idea was to make middleware which contains GUI to display blocks and board, and allow players to move blocks. Middleware is connected with game (another app), which count score and do another basic things. And here comes my question. I want to split display into two parts - one for middleware GUI and second for game e.g. displaying score.

I found Fragments, but everywhere it was used in one application. Is it possible to display two fragments from differen apps at one time?

Thanks, for help :)

Answer (score 0):

> Is it possible to display two fragments from differen apps at one time?

No, sorry.

You can use `RemoteViews` — what app widgets and custom notifications use — to pass bits of UI from one app to another, though `RemoteViews` are limited.

You could create your own `RemoteViews`-like system, marshalling instructions for how to build a UI and pass events, then use that between your apps.

On Android 7.0+, the user could enter split-screen mode, showing two activities side-by-side, and you might leverage that for what you are seeking.

Comment: As I thought so... I will take a look for RemoteViews, but I'm not sure if it wil solve my problem :) 
In Android 6.0 is it possible also to open two activities side by side but only in Samsung probably :)

Comment: @mateusz298: Yes, some Samsung and LG devices offer split-screen functionality prior to Android 7.0.

Answer (score 0):

You should take a look here:
https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/multi-window.html

But as CommonsWare mentioned, it is only from Android 7.0 officially.

With same hacks, you can use it it lower Android versions too, but root necessary.

Or you have to use manufacturer specific APIs, if it is supported, like on Samsung devices:
http://developer.samsung.com/s-pen-sdk/technical-docs/Designing-For-The-Galaxy-Note-Creating-Multi-Window-Apps

Comment: I know this Samsung idea, but I cannot use it because my middleware should be universal, but thanks for reply :)

Answer (score 0):

So, I think the best option would be splitting middleware GUI for GUI and part for game, so game would send data to middleware and it would display it.